# How do I clone a local git folder(repo) to a remote server

Tags: git

I see this question asked many times. I've tried every answer.

- [this one doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947327/how-do-i-clone-my-git-reposity-to-a-remote-machine).
- [this one doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631346/moving-a-git-repo-to-another-server).
- [this one doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978650/how-do-i-move-my-local-git-repository-to-a-remote-git-repository)
- [this one is incomplete and therefore doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547709/pushing-local-repository-to-server)
- [this one creates a bundle which would need twice the space on both sides](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299802/migrate-git-repositories). not a good solution for a large repo

Not one of them has actually worked. Maybe something changed in git since they were written?

To be clear: I have a local checkout, I want a similar checkout on remote. I know I can use `scp -r . ssh://remote/somefolder` but scp is extremely slow so I'd prefer to do it with git.

Some answers said

- on remote

  ```
  $ mkdir somefolder
  $ cd somefolder
  $ git init
  ```
- on local

  ```
  $ git push --mirror ssh://remote/somefolder

  remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
  remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
  remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
  remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
  remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
  remote: error: 
  remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
  remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
  remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
  remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
  remote: error: other way.  
  remote: error: 
  remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
  remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
  ```

Other answers said

- on remote

  ```
  $ mkdir somefolder
  $ cd somefolder
  $ git init --bare
  ```

This fails. Now `somefolder` is full of git files instead of having a `.git` folder

Okay let's guess

- on remote

  ```
  $ mkdir somefolder
  $ cd somefolder
  $ git init --bare .git
  ```

Hey I have a `.git` folder inside `somefolder`

Let's push

- on local

  ```
  $ git push --mirror ssh://remote/somefolder/
  ```
- on remote

  ```
  $ cd somefolder
  $ git status
  fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
  ```

The question I want answered is, how do I *push* a local repo to a remote server such that on the remote server it acts exactly the same as if I had cloned the repo.

In other words if I could do this

- on remote

  git clone ssh://local/somefolder/

I can't do that though since local doesn't have public ip address serving ssh. So instead I want to push it. When it's done remote should have

```
somefolder
|
+- .git
```

and the master branch should be checked out, just like it would if I had cloned.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

on remote:

```
$ mkdir somefolder
$ cd somefolder
$ git init --bare
```

on local

```
$ git push ssh://remote/somefolder/
```

on remote again, only first time

```
$ mkdir someotherfolder
$ cd someotherfolder
$ git clone somefolder .
```

on remote again, subsequent calls
   $git pull

I think you could do this automatically, on subsequent calls with [hooks](http://githooks.com/)

Comment: why would I want to have a repo on remote twice?

Comment: Yea, I get that. My point is I don't want to use the double the storage. But yet it will work and I can delete the `somefolder` after I'm done. It just seems round about. That's just one step removed from just making a .tar.gz of my local folder.

Answer (score 1):

What if you do exactly what it says in the error message:

```
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
```

Run this in the remote, non-bare repository:

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
```

The warning is there for a reason, though; this will interact poorly with edits to the working tree on remote. If you do this, never edit files directly on the remote without committing them!

Comment: Yes, I saw that. So I guess on remote I need to `git init; git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore` then on local do the push, then on remote `git config --unset receive.denyCurrentBranch`? Kind of thought there'd be some other way although that's not horrible.

Comment: The _problem_ is that you are trying to push onto the branch that is "checked out" on the remote repository. You could just check out anything with --detach on the remote repository and then you won't see this problem.

Comment: You can unset if you need to, but I'm not sure why you wouldn't just keep it set if you plan on doing this more than once.